# Why the REGEXP2 gives a syntax error on SQLite?

Tags: regex, sqlite, user-defined-functions

I define 2 functions:

```
sqlite3_create_function( m_db.db(), "regexp", 2, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, mysqlite_regexp, NULL, NULL );
sqlite3_create_function( m_db.db(), "regexp2", 2, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, mysqlite_regexp2, NULL, NULL ) ;
```

And if i made a query like `SELECT Images.ImageID FROM Images WHERE Images.Filename REGEXP \"truc\"`, only with REGEXP it works.

With REGEXP2 I have an error, *"near REGEXP2: syntax error"*

Why?

Comment: `REGEXP` is an operator; you’re defining functions, so it would be `WHERE REGEXP2(Images.Filename, "truc")`… maybe. That’s a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [REGEXP operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#regexp) is defined to redirect to the `regexp` user function.

Except `GLOB`, no other operators are defined in this way.
If you want to call other functions, you have to call them as functions:

```
SELECT ImageID FROM Images WHERE regexp('truc', Filename);
SELECT ImageID FROM Images WHERE regexp2('truc', Filename);
```